# subset function in R with more than one conditions

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to use the subset function in R with more than one conditions.
What I'm trying to do looks something like:

```
fifties <- subset(ex, ex$"age" == 55:59)
```

My intention is to filter people with ages 55-59 from the dataframe "ex".
But the code above does not work and gives a warning message instead.

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

So I've been trying a different approach:

```
fiftyfive <- subset(ex, ex$"age" == 55)
fiftysix <- subset(ex, ex$"age" == 56)
fiftyseven <- subset(ex, ex$"age" == 57)
fiftyeight <- subset(ex, ex$"age" == 58)
fiftynine <- subset(ex, ex$"age" == 59)

fifties <- rbind(fiftyfive, fiftysix, fiftyseven, fiftyeight, fiftynine)
```

This works fine, but obviously isn't neat and quite tedious to do each time.
I was wondering if there is a better solution to this problem! Any ideas...?

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto thanks for your answer! I see now that it was a stupid question to ask..